# How to display different text on different rectangles in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, render

I have created a Pygame application where I have about 25 rectangles. I want to display 25 different text values (which is a numerical value but typecasted in `str`- I mention this because I believe we need string in the first argument) at the center of the rectangle. I have imported a csv file that contains data.

```py
def draw_point(text, pos):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)
    img = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
    window.blit(img, pos)

def loop_func():
    count = 0
    while count < total_length:
        data = data_pass[count] # data_pass is an empty list
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,255,255), (20, 20, width, height)) 
        draw_point(data, (width // 2, height // 2))
```

According to the `loop_func()` function, the variable '**data**' should be updated with a new value in every loop, and it is updating because I checked with the `print()` function. But when I pass the variable to the `draw_point()` function, it seems the function does not display the desired value. This is my output:

[image]

It is actually 25 different rectangles with an almost similar background color. I followed everything from the Pygame tutorial, but I am getting a very ugly font, and among 25 rectangles, only 1 rectangle shows the text at its center.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the text is drawn on top of each other. You need to draw the text at different positions. e.g.:

```py
def loop_func():
    count = 0
    while count < total_length:
        data = data_pass[count] # data_pass is an empty list
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,255,255), (20, 20, width, height)) 
        draw_point(data, (width // 2, height // 2 + count * 20))
```

If you want to draw the text at different times (counter), you need to change the text by time. See for example [How to display dynamically in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453574/how-to-display-dynamically-in-pygame/56454295#56454295)